# Was before 'Big bang' every single matter particle surrounded by other particles due to space curvature?

Tags: cosmology, universe, curvature, big-bang

Was before 'Big bang' every single matter particle surrounded by other particles due to space curvature? In that case gravity would not be concentrated towards only one point if the space were flat? Something like the 2D difference between points attracting each other on a plate which will tend to concentrate in one point and in the other case on a sphere where there would not be such an accumulation point?

Comment: I did not understand the question after *Something like...*

Answer (score 1):

There were no matter particles at all "before", or at the exact time of the Big Bang.

Particles formed a short time *after* the Big Bang. The laws of physics (quantum mechanics and general relativity) as we know them currently, are not properly applicable before about $10^{-12}$ seconds after the Big Bang. So talking about particles and curvature before then would be pure speculation.

There are attempts to answer similar questions in the field of [quantum gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity#Candidate_theories) which is an highly active area of research.